# PHP MySQL Insert Rows Limit

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a PHP script that inserts about 2000+ rows into the mysql database.

But for my case it stops after 500+ rows. Any idea what could be the issue?

I have verified by also displaying out the data before insertion and it shows all the 2000+ rows of data.

Came across this posting [MySQL insert limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336012/mysql-insert-limit) but I am currently using MySQL in Windows.

How could I remove the limit?

Comment: Your page seems getting time out.Try adding `set_time_limit(0);` in your code.

Comment: can you show us the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of the time limit exceeding 30 sec.... 
To overcome this , you can follow either the following steps

```
1. Use this code 
 set_time_limit(0);
 in your php before inserting into db
```

or

```
2. Change the time limit in your php.ini file ...
```

1 option is better and temperory measure though

Answer (score 0):

Open **Php.ini** and go to **line no. 442**. You will get following line

```
  max_execution_time = 30
```

**set** max_execution_time **to "0"** which is means no limit or set other value in seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can put this PHP code before inserting into the database

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```